# Process the text once voice input is stopped from SFSpeechRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

I am developing a Voice to Text application using iOS SFSpeechRecognizer API.

Found a great [tutorial here:](https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/) and it worked fine.

I wanted to process the text and perform some action as soon as the voice input is stopped. So, was curious whether there is a delegate method available for SFSpeechRecognizer which can recognise when the voice input is stopped so that I can capture the input and process further?

Answer (score 1):

> So, was curious whether there is a delegate method available for SFSpeechRecognizer which can recognise when the voice input is stopped so that I can capture the input and process further?

Not built into the SFSpeechRecognizer API, no. On the contrary, that is exactly why you *must* provide interface that allows the user to *tell* the recognizer that the input is finished (e.g. a Done button of some sort). Your app will be rejected if you omit that interface.

Comment: If we record the audio and send the entire audio for conversion would that be ok.

Comment: If you send a file for conversion, obviously the end of the input is the end of the file. And you can do that. But that is not what you seemed to be asking. You asked "whether there is a delegate method available for SFSpeechRecognizer which can recognise when the voice input is stopped". No.

Comment: So if we use an approach as in https://github.com/fulldecent/FDSoundActivatedRecorder would that be ok. This is not my question but am just curious to know your insight on it.

Comment: If you want to know how to record a file with automatic stopping when the sound stops (falls below a certain threshold for a certain amount of time), you should ask a question about that (or do some research on it, at least). But I repeat, that is not what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution maybe to use a third party library like [FDSoundActivatedRecorder](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDSoundActivatedRecorder) which start recording when sound is detected and
stops recording when the user is done talking.

Then you can use the recorded audio as in this [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-convert-speech-to-text-using-sfspeechrecognizer) to convert it to text in a go.

```
func transcribeAudio(url: URL) {
    // create a new recognizer and point it at our audio
    let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
    let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: url)

    // start recognition!
    recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { [unowned self] (result, error) in
        // abort if we didn't get any transcription back
        guard let result = result else {
            print("There was an error: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        // if we got the final transcription back, print it
        if result.isFinal {
            // pull out the best transcription...
            print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to commit to using a 3rd party Library, deeply integrating it and finally getting the app rejected by Apple. Anyways, thanks for the inputs

Comment: So you mean to say that using third party libraries can get your app rejected?

Comment: Might be a possibility. You never know. If Apple reviewers decide to reject ur app based on using this library, what else can you do :-P

Comment: The binaries are checked at the time of uploading I guess. Well the way this library works is that it checks the output levels at an interval of 0.05 second and calculates the moving average if there is a fall then the recording is stopped. If you want you can have a look at the source code and rewrite the functionality yourself.

Comment: Here is the link to the relevant file. The code is well documented so rewriting it won't be an issue.
https://github.com/fulldecent/FDSoundActivatedRecorder/blob/master/FDSoundActivatedRecorder/FDSoundActivatedRecorder/FDSoundActivatedRecorder.swift

Comment: Not compatible with latest API's. Were you able to successfully run the demo? Looks like this has not been optimized using latest API's for Swift